# Pandas Dataframe: Replacing or Realigning Overlapping Timesheet Entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I am working with Timesheet data coming out of one system and into another. The timesheet data from the source system has overlapping entries whereas the destination system cannot. The business rule is: "In the event of an overlapping entry, the intervening event will supersede the current event until the intervening event finishes and then the current event will recommence". This is better explained with the data.

Source system (with overlapping):

| Employee | Shift | Type | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SHFT-1 | Sleep | 19/06/2023 10:00PM | 20/06/2023 07:00AM |
| 1 | ACT-1 | Disturbance | 19/06/2023 11:00PM | 19/06/2023 11:30PM |
| 1 | ACT-2 | Disturbance | 20/06/2023 02:00AM | 20/06/2023 03:00AM |
| 1 | ACT-3 | Disturbance | 20/06/2023 06:30AM | 20/06/2023 07:00AM |

Effectively, worker was scheduled to sleep from 10pm-7am and had 3 disturbances during that shift. When the disturbance finished, they "clocked" back into the Sleep task, except for the last one as it was the end of the Sleep task.

The destination system expects the data like this:

| Employee | Shift | Type | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SHFT-1 | Sleep | 19/06/2023 10:00PM | 19/06/2023 11:00PM |
| 1 | ACT-1 | Disturbance | 19/06/2023 11:00PM | 20/06/2023 11:30PM |
| 1 | SHFT-1 | Sleep | 19/06/2023 11:30PM | 20/06/2023 02:00AM |
| 1 | ACT-2 | Disturbance | 20/06/2023 02:00AM | 20/06/2023 03:00AM |
| 1 | SHFT-1 | Sleep | 20/06/2023 03:00AM | 20/06/2023 06:30AM |
| 1 | ACT-3 | Disturbance | 20/06/2023 06:30AM | 20/06/2023 07:00AM |

I have several ideas on how I can brute-force this logic, but I am looking for something a bit more sophisticated than running something like:
`while not_finished iterate_all not_finished = changes_occured`

Is there a vectorized way I can do this?

Comment: If you look at `df[['Start', 'End']].stack()` from your example it's the new `End` column values (excluding the Sleep row). Shift and insert the initial Start time and it's the new Start column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd post the "brute-force" method as maybe this might spur someone on how I could do this in a non-newb way.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Employee ID': [1,1,1,1],
    'Shift':['SFT-1','ACT-1','ACT-2','ACT-3'],
    'Type':['Sleep','Disturbance','Disturbance','Disturbance'],
    'Start': ['19/06/2023 10:00PM', '19/06/2023 10:00PM', '20/06/2023 02:00AM', '20/06/2023 06:30AM' ],
    'Finish': ['20/06/2023 07:00AM', '19/06/2023 11:30PM', '20/06/2023 03:00AM', '20/06/2023 07:00AM'],
    'Duration':[540,30,60,30]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert columns to datetime type
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Finish'])

# Sort DataFrame by Start time
df = df.sort_values('Start').reset_index(drop=True)

complete = False
row = 0

while (not complete):

    this_row = df.iloc[row]
    next_row = df.iloc[row + 1]
    
    # If next row starts before this one finishes, then it is overlapping.
    if this_row['Finish'] > next_row['Start']:
             
        # Create new line, set start to next_row finish, finish to this_row finish,
        # calculate duration
        new_row = this_row.copy()
        new_row['Shift'] = new_row['Shift'] + ' O/L'
        new_row['Start'] = next_row['Finish']
        # Finish already set by copy.
        new_row['Duration'] = (new_row['Finish'] - new_row['Start']).seconds / 60.0
        
        # Set df's this_row finish to next_row start, calculate duration.
        df.at[row, 'Finish'] = next_row['Start']
        df.at[row, 'Duration'] = (df.at[row, 'Finish'] - df.at[row, 'Start']).seconds / 60.0
        
        # Insert new_row after next_row
        df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:row+2], new_row.to_frame(1).T, df.iloc[row+2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

    row += 1
    
    # Check for completeness.    
    complete = (row == df.shape[0] - 1)
    
# Drop all rows with 0 duration.
df = df[df['Duration'] > 0]
```

Comment: Going to mark this as best answer for now - but still keen to see if anyone comes up with a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a Pandas solution, but I didn't get the chance to fine-tune it further, I will post it here for reference, and please feel free to modify it or suggest some changes.

Note: I used the same dataframe structure and data you shared in the question (Employee, Shift, Type, Start, End).
Sample Code:

```
st_df = (
    testing
    .assign(
        Start= lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(df_.Start),
        End= lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(df_.End),
        dates= lambda df_: df_.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row["Start"], row["End"], freq="30T"), axis=1)
    )
    .explode("dates")
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["dates"], keep="last")
    .sort_values(by="dates")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .set_index(["Employee", "Shift", "Type", "Start", "End"])
    .apply(lambda x: x.diff())
    .reset_index()
    .loc[ lambda df_: (df_.Start != df_.shift(-1).Start)]
    .drop(columns=["dates"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
display(st_df)
```

Expected output:

[image]

I have created a new column called `dates`, in which I created data ranges (each 30 mins is a new row) and explode them after. Then I use them to apply the difference function `series.diff()` to calculate the difference between each real shift.

Finally, I do a comparison between the final df (after the series.diff()) and a masked one row shifted version of it so that I delete the multiple occurrences that I don't need.

For instance, if I have one hour of sleep from 10pm till 11 pm, I will have in my final dataframe two row of 30 mins time ranges one from 10 till 10:30 and another from 10:30 till 11, so I dropped one of them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I can't get this code to run but thank you anyway! Also in your screenshot, the times are not continuous, they still overlap.